# Instantiating class method without instantiating the class in PHP no longer possible?

Tags: php, class, methods

I'm not sure if I'm losing it or what.  I recently jumped back into PHP after a much needed break, and I'm trying to do something that I've always been able to do:  call a public class method without instantiating the class.  Example:

```
  class Utils 
  {
    public function getTime() 
    {
      return time();
    }
  }

  $time = Utils::getTime();
  echo $time;
```

I used to do this all the time (about two or three years ago), but after hopping into PHP 5.3 on a new sandbox environment that I set up, I keep getting

```
  Fatal error: Call to undefined function getTime() in /mnt/richard/index.php on line 24
```

Am I missing something silly here?  Or is the use of public class methods without class instantiation a now deprecated feature in PHP? Oh how times have changed...

**My overall goal is to be able to create methods that belong to a grouped set of classes that can be called in the global scope within other methods and classes.  Any help will be much appreciated.  Thanks.**

Comment: Do you expect to be able to also invoke those methods on objects instantiated from the class (e.g. `$foo->getTime();`) or do you just want to use the class as some sort of namespace?

Comment: This code works fine for me, copy & pasted.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. This should give you at least some warning.

Comment: @Lior Cohen Nope. I don't see any error. just outputs `1342245440`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @LiorCohen The class is primarily used as a namespace / prefix, for organizational purposes.  I actually set up error_reporting to E_ALL right now and I see now that I was incorrectly referring to an instantiated method within the method I was attempting agnostically calling (i.e. $this->varName ), when there is no instantiated parent object for $this to even be relevant.  Silly mistake.  Thank you much for the prompt replies.

Comment: @richardgirges: regardless, you shouldn't be calling instance methods as static ones on a class, even if PHP allows you to do so. When invoking `Utils::getTime();`, you are essentially calling an instance method from a static context. You should define `getTime()` as `public static` instead.

Comment: @LiorCohen, you should post that as an actual answer... that's the right way to do it (though in my experience, PHP has never cared unless the method tried to use `$this`)

Comment: Also, fwiw, I copied & pasted the code and ran with 5.3.10, no error + good results.

Comment: @ctrahey: posted as answer. That is weird, but then, so is PHP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling instance methods as static ones on a class, even if PHP allows you to do so. When invoking:

```
 Utils::getTime();
```

you are calling an instance method from a static context. You should define `getTime` like this instead:

```
class Utils 
{
    public static function getTime() 
    {
       // You can't use $this in here. This is a static function. No instance exists.
       return time();
    }
}
```